# how to delete a developers workspace

Tags: tfs

A developer has left, and his workstation is now formatted.  TFS thinks he still has files checked out.  Clearly he'll never be checking them in.  How do I tell TFS to forget about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How to: Undo another users check-out](http://blogs.msdn.com/mrod/archive/2007/01/08/undoing-a-checkout-that-belongs-to-another-user.aspx)

[How to: Remove a Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245474.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Deleting a workspace, and undoing another user check-out (and much more!) can be done using the [Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) tool (it is free).  Specifically look at Workspace Sidekick and Status Sidekick:

Workspace screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [attrice.info](http://www.attrice.info/images/workspace_sk_screen.gif))</sub>
Status screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [attrice.info](http://www.attrice.info/images/status_sk_screen.gif))</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Forcibly check them out by another user and then commit them. ("Break lock")