# TFS Locking Issue

Tags: asp.net

My System Administrator renamed my computer. So where it was "MyLaptop2" it is now just "MyLaptop".

So now all my source control bindings and checked out files are looking for a workspace with "MyLaptop2".

I have two particular file (classic asp) now can't be checked in/out because it is locked by MyLaptop2

How can I update the file (classic asp) in TFS now?

Answer (score 0):

[This question is slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815562/how-to-delete-a-developers-workspace), but the solution is the same. Undo the changes, or simply delete the old workspace from TFS